# Convert OSM XML file to GeoJSON yields nothing

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, convert, xml

I am very new to the map making world and I am trying to extract a body of water using OpenStreetMap, convert the XML file to a GeoJSON file so that I can upload it to Datawrapper.

This is the file I am interested in: https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/13737936. I have saved this as the XML file and am trying to convert it to GeoJSON using https://tyrasd.github.io/osmtogeojson/. However, it returns an empty file such as

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": []
}
```

I have tried this on the command line as well and it returns the same thing. Why is this happening? I am not used to looking at XML files so I am not sure if there is anything wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `/full` to the API URL like:

> https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/13737936/full

and copy that XML.

Gives:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "relation/13737936",
            "properties": {
                "timestamp": "2022-01-31T04:54:48Z",
                "version": "3",
                "changeset": "116804664",
                "user": "DENelson83",
                "uid": "14512",
                "name": "ᐊᒃᓴᕐᓂᖅ Chesterfield Inlet",
                "name:en": "Chesterfield Inlet",
                "name:iu": "ᐊᒃᓴᕐᓂᖅ",
                "natural": "bay",
                "ocean": "yes",
                "ref:gnbc": "OADJR",
                "source": "NRCan-CanVec-10.0",
                "type": "multipolygon",
                "wikidata": "Q948291",
                "id": "relation/13737936"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -92.57855,
                            63.79285
                        ],
                        [...
```